# Unknown error occured?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

When I install the Craft Commerce plugin on Craft CMS, I found an error "unknown error occurred".  Please tell me about this error and how to fix it. I will be very thankful.

I have a lot of google search on it but nothing useful.

Thanks again.

Comment: If you look in your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files and search for [error], you should the exact error message. You could eventually post it here

Answer (score 1):

it is simple ! only edit php.ini file which is in your xampp folder . increase msql connection time and increase cache i.e limit size and that solve.